# sed Pattern to insert characters after a number and before ]

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, terminal

I have a big file as below

```
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10               ],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10               ],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10               ],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11],
```

Now I want to update the whole file to add a comma`(,)` and number`(12)` so it looks like below

```
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,                 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,                 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,                 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
```

I can't do this manually, is there any easier sed/awk command to do this?

I tried `sed 's/]/, 12]/g' <path_to_the_file>` but this does it in the wrong way than I wanted

```
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10                , 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10                , 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10                , 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,    8, 9, 10,             11, 12],
```

This is not the result I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture all the space characters that appear before `]`

```bash
sed 's/\( *\)]/,\1 12]/'
```

Comment: Note that in the example input, the `],` at the end of the line isn't quite aligned -- it's one character shorter on lines missing the last field. If this *also* needs to be corrected, the `sed` script will be more complicated.

Comment: `sed 's/\( *\)]/,\1 12]/; s/\(  [^ ]*\)$/ \1/' file`